# Ansible Tower: 'extra_vars' with multiple variables are ignored when running with curl in cmd

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-template, ansible-tower

Can some one tell how to pass multiple `extra_vars` variables from the command line which will run the Job Template in Tower?

I've followed Ansible documentaion https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/job_templates.html#passing-extra-variables-to-provisioning-callbacks

```bash
curl -f -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XPOST \
                  -d '{"host_config_key": "efref3d9-740f-429c-43r2-15t326b76", "extra_vars": "{\"Job_ID\": \"24\"},{\"job_templates\": \"test99\"}"}' \
                  https://tower-ansible.com:443/api/v2/job_templates/822/callback/ -k
```

For single variable it's working. Below `curl` command works with single extra variable

```bash
curl -f -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XPOST     -d '{"host_config_key": "efref3d9-740f-429c-43r2-15t323b76", "extra_vars": "{\"job_id\": \"24\"}"}'     https://tower-ansible.com:443/api/v2/job_templates/822/callback/ -k
```

Answer (score 0):

According the documentation about [Passing Extra Variables to Provisioning Callbacks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/job_templates.html#passing-extra-variables-to-provisioning-callbacks) you have referenced you may

> *Use the following JSON format as an example when adding your own `extra_vars` to be passed*

```json
"extra_vars": {"variable1":"value1","variable2":"value2",...}
```

instead of as in your provided example

```json
"extra_vars": {"variable1":"value1"},{"variable2":"value2"}
```

Comment: I tried with this aswell, but its not working.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what you have tried and what is not working? To do so can you examples together with resulting outputs and by editing the initial question?